# Could not find the file specified?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, shader

I get a really annoying error, code is fine but it can't find the files.

```
Output:
.\res\shadersbasicVertex.vs (The system cannot find the file specified) <-- yes it does actually say '\shadersbasicVertex.vs'
```

heres where I load the resources (or where I specify the path)

```
    shaderReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./res/shaders" + fileName));
```

libraries im using: lwjgl

```
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.base.engine.ResourceLoader.loadShader(ResourceLoader.java:15)
at com.base.engine.Game.<init>(Game.java:20)
at com.base.engine.MainComponent.<init>(MainComponent.java:20)
at com.base.engine.MainComponent.main(MainComponent.java:124)
```

my shader folders are located at:
C:\Users\Badfitz66\workspace\Rain\Game engine\res\shaders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes, presumably `fileName` is `"basicVertex.vs"`. Put that on the end of `"./res/shaders"` and you'll get `.\res\shadersbasicVertex.vs`. You need an extra slash:

```
shaderReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./res/shaders/" + fileName));
```

Or you could use the `File` API to resolve the path:

```
File file = new File(new File("res", "shaders"), fileName);
shaderReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

Or better yet:

```
shaderReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("res", "shaders", fileName));
```

Note that:

- This has nothing to do with OpenGL or anything 3d - you're just opening a file
- `FileReader` *always* uses the platform default encoding; I would recommend using an approach which allows you to specify the encoding - the last example does, but defaults to UTF-8.